# In futuristic domed cities terrified of pandemics, how would spread be prevented between domes?

Tags: cities, diseases, safety

With the Covid-19 pandemic currently underway, it's a bit easier to imagine a world where the virus is more lethal and even brutal measures are used to contain the spread of diseases. In the scenario presented, the only way for disease to spread is from one dome to another. Some domes are closer  to an exit from the system and greater exposure to danger.

What futuristic tools would be used to safeguard domes from people and goods moving back and forth?

Comment: "Some domes are closer to an exit from the system" - what is "the system"? A continent?

Comment: A system would be a group of domes connected to each other. One would be able to seal off individual domes or to go from dome to done without going outside depending on permission.

Comment: Are the domes city-sized, or house-sized?

Comment: I'm imagining them as being parts of a city. Most would spend the majority of their lives in one dome, while others would commute from one dome to another daily.

Answer (score 5):

**Drones, drones, drones.**

The people huddle in fear.  No-one leaves a dome and no-one enters.   Commerce, industry and anything requiring one leave the safety of ones own dome are carried out by robots.  These robots have copper and silver skins to destroy microbes that land on them, and are sterilized on moving from dome to dome.  Some might be autonomous but some might be avatars of a pilot; perhaps her face appears on the face of the robot.

Goods are sterilized with ionizing radiation before entering a dome.

Comment: Goods could also sit in quarantine for a few weeks. Viruses don't last too long outside of a host.

Comment: The simplest answer is that no one ever travels! Essential goods could get shipped in sealed robotic trains and the whole thing gets autoclaved in a giant oven as it enters a new city. It's crude, low tech and oppressive, but simple and effective. The rarity of a physical rather than virtual traveler would make people panic and rush around introducing emergency procedures. You could even marry someone you never met in person and live in VR, where carefully screened sperm is transferred after extensive testing (or even reconstituted gene-by-gene in the new city) to have children.

Answer (score 2):

During the times of the Black Death the places which managed to effectively limit the hit were those which enforced a strict lock out and quarantine to people and goods. Actually it's back in those times that the term quarantine was born, since ships had to spend 40 days of isolation before being allowed to disembark.

Few hundreds year later we can send probes past the heliosphere but still the most effective means of protection seems to be a strict lock out and quarantine.

Thanks to the mighty power of extrapolation, I dare to say that even in your scenario a strict lock out with quarantine will work best.

Comment: Note for people who do not speak a Romance language: French *quarante* (pronounced /ka.ʁɑ̃t/, more of less kah-rant), Italian *quaranta*, Spanish *cuarenta* mean "forty".

Comment: You'd use the same quarantine procedure currently used in Canada for students wanting to fly home to Nunavut. They are kept in isolation and under guard at specified hotels for two weeks, and if they clear with no symptoms, they're taken by dedicated bus straight to a cleaned charter aircraft, bypassing the airport facilities,and flown home. In this scenario, before anyone moves between domes they have to spend time in isolation in a dedicated quarantine dome before they're allowed to continue on.

Answer (score 1):

**A high degree of robotization and complex quarantine procedures.**

In this society so scared of contamination, transport of goods would likely have great investments so that humans were no longer necessary, with robots doing most, if not all of the work. That way, at least the risk of a driver being infected when going to a dome to another would be greatly reduced.

Now this second part is assuming the disease can be present in objects: very complex and bureaucratic measures would be adopted at the entrances of said domes. The cargo would likely be sterilized when entering and leaving the domes, and would be subjected to heavy inspection for any pathogenic presence, which would most likely be mostly made by robots, as it'd be safer for humans and more effective, as they'd be equipped with specialized scanners. Either way, food products would likely need to be placed in containers capable of preserving them for long periods, as these verifications would likely take a while. People who did transport stuff between domes would likely be seen similarly to doctors, having higher salaries and being able to retire earlier due to it being seen as an unhealthy job.